# Orchard CMS load error

Tags: jquery, lucene, orchardcms

I have just installed Orchard CMS via Web Platform Installer 5.0. The installation went fine. When launched via WebMatrix I am getting the following error.

> **A 'script' named 'jQuery' could not be found.**

```
Line 13: <meta charset="utf-8" />
Line 14: <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title>
Line 15: @Display(Model.Head)
Line 16: <script> (function (d) { d.className = "dyn" + d.className.substring(6, >d.className.length); })(document.documentElement);</script>
Line 17: </head>
```

Also I don't want to use WebMatrix IDE. I opened the website (using file system) with my VS 2012. Tried running from there and received following compilation error:

> Error  1   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   C:\Users\Subrata\Documents\My Web Sites\orchard\Modules\Lucene\Lucene.csproj    1

I also cloned the source code from Github using

```
git clone https://github.com/subtata-emfluence/Orchard.git
```

Somebody help me with how I can get rid of above issues and configure my first site!

Comment: Which version of Orchard did you install?

Comment: Web PI only showed me the release date, i.e. 5/18/2016. What is the way to know the version I have installed?

Comment: Take a look at the logs, which should be under App_Data/logs

Comment: There are 3 log files showing - `orchard-debug`, `orchard-error` and `orchard-recipes` but they all are empty. Nothing is in there. Also I don't want to use WebMatrix IDE. I opened the website (using file system) with my VS 2012. Tried running from there and received following compilation error: `Error 1 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. C:\Users\Subrata\Documents\My Web Sites\orchard\Modules\Lucene\Lucene.csproj 1 `. Is WebMatrix the only option?

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous! I run again just now from WebMartix again and its loaded !!! yesterday it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is happened to me many times. always thought it was down the new resources pipeline. once you build it goes away.
Haven't tried but chances are that WebMatrix might pickup on the Gulp script and build the dependencies for you...
Working with VS2012 might not be the best while developing with Orchard

Comment: Thank you for your nice clarification and suggestion. Is VS 2012 version not recommended only or all of them? Reason I am asking is VS 2015 Community edition installed in my PC as well. If I don't use an IDE, how would I debug if required? May I please request you to take a look at my other post as well. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549895/orchard-cms-where-new-theme-structure-and-files-get-saved-when-installed-from-g.

Comment: VS2015 is best as the latest version uses Gulp to get all your Assets, Scripts, etc