# Orchard CMS: Where new theme structure and files get saved when installed from Gallery

Tags: orchardcms

I have a couple of general questions please. Just stepping into Orchard CMS. So apology if they look stupid!

Today I installed a theme called `Metro` from Theme Gallery. It is visible on theme selection page as well. But where the files and folder structure are got saved in Orchard CMS? I looked into `Theme` folder but it is not there. I want to see how the structure is placed so that I can create one myself

One more thing. Theme .png file shows a nice layout but when I activate it the layout comes up completely different. Why is this?

And finally, I installed my site using Orchard's web interface and it is running fine. But when I tried to run `orchard > codegen theme CreditLine`, it said **Command codegen doesn't exist**.

I then run Setup utility from command prompt (`orchard >`) and it displayed

> A previous Orchard installation was detected in this database with this table prefix.

Which clearly says the setup I did through web interface was successful. But still I am not able to run `codegen` command or even `help codegen`. The latter command shows `Command codegen doesn't exist`!

**Orchard version: v.1.10.1.0**

Answer (score 2):

1) It should be installed under `Themes/TheThemeName`, or locally, under `src/Orchard.Web/Themes/TheThemeName`

2) It could be that you installed an old theme. Not sure because you don't give many details over what goes wrong.

3) You first have to enable the `codegen` module. Do this by starting up your Orchard, go to modules => Codegen => Enable. Or run in the `orchard.exe`: `feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I used the command line tool. `orchard > feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration`, which said `Code Generation was enabled`. But typing `help codegen` says `Command codegen does not exist`. It is not in the list of available commands. Evidently when I tried `codegen theme BoxingDay` it said command is not available. What I am doing wrong? I want to create a new theme from scratch.

Comment: I remember having issues when enabling the Codegen from the command line. Delete all your App_Data and just enable it through the admin interface, that one never fails

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of Googling and struggle I found a nice community [here](https://gitter.im/OrchardCMS/Orchard) where I got my answer!

[Orchard Repository on Github](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard) defaults to `dev` branch which I overlooked completely when cloned it for the first time! So I removed everything from my local and cloned the source again but from `master` branch this time.

No more compilation error or Command Line issue popped up. `Orchard.CodeGeneration` feature got enabled from CLI this time without a problem. Everything else seems to be working fine as well.

**Steps:**
1. Removed source from my local which I cloned from `dev` branch initialy
2. Cloned Orchard from master branch
3. Opened solution in VS2015
4. Compiled, run and setup my first site
5. And finally ran `feature enable Orchard.CodeGeneration` from `orchard` command prompt.